# Pipeline Resource * Input Must be Valid

Tags: azure-pipelines

I'm following [pipeline resource triggers docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops#configure-pipeline-resource-triggers) and I constructed my pipeline that looks like this.

```yaml
15 resources:
16   pipelines:
17     - pipeline: buildPipeline
18       source: template-ci # azure devops pipeline name (defined in ADO UI!)
19       project: $(System.TeamProject) # azure devops project name
20       trigger:
21         branches:
22           include:
23           - main
```

Unfortunately, the above definition throws this error `/devops/ct.yml (Line: 17, Col: 17): Pipeline Resource buildPipeline Input Must be Valid.`

When I look at line `17 - pipeline: buildPipeline` it looks perfectly fine what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 7):

## Context

Turns out that the error is not referring to a single line (`17`) of configuration but, to the resource definition (`pipeline resource`) that, in my case, is defined from line `17` to `23`.

## Problem

My pipeline problem lies on the line number `19`. Apparently, Azure Pipelines don't like runtime expression `project: $(System.TeamProject)` for pipeline resource definition.

## Solutions

1. Removing line `19` fixed the problem.
2. Replace `$(System.TeamProject)` with **the project name specified in azure devops**. e.g for this url `https://dev.azure.com/your-org-name/Your Project Name` the project name would be `Your Project Name`. Resulting with yaml config that looks like below.

```yaml
19       project: Your Project Nam
```

Answer (score 7):

I had the same error message but in my case the problem was that there were two pipelines with the name specified for the source parameter (`template_ci`) in the example above. When I renamed one of them it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had to correct the branch name from `main` to `master` and it worked.

Also correct the project name on Azure, found in the link (https://dev.azure.com/xxx/ProjectName)